# How to store pictures in same app like gallery after taking pictures with custom camera In android

Tags: java, android-studio, storage, image-gallery, android-camera2

I have made custom camera and want to store images in same application instead of built-in gallery.I am taking pictures with my custom camera and want to make separate gallery for that application. A small thumbnail should appear on corner after taking the pictures then on clicking thumbnail it should open my custom galley. So far i have made custom camera which is taking pictures and videos now i want to store them in separate gallery. Please help me out how can i do this task and share your code if you have done already. Your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can learn about android file storage management using this link.
[Android File Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage). You can read here about differences between Internal storage(Private Location) and external storage(Public location) .
[Data Storage Internal/External](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files)

As you are not very clear with the description, so there can be 2 possibilities

- You want a private location for your images with no other app can access. Private location has benefit that data which you save in this location is app specific. But at the same time you'll also be not able to access the images from file explorer.
- You want a public location for your images but a specific place where only your app images are available. Public location has benefit that data (files, images) which you save can be publicly accessible via file explorer, at the same time it can be accessed by other apps in your phone which are granted storage permission.

[Saving file in Internal Storage (Private location for app)](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/internal)

Hope this helps and resolves your query.